# Modal window doesnt open from another modal window

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I have a modal window with a button. The button must open another modal window, but nothing happens. I tested with 'alert': script runs.

heres html:

```
<a href="#" id='goto'  onclick="calc();">Рассчитать</a>
```

and heres js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('a#goto').click( function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Where is calc()? Where is the part where you try to open the modal? Are you using jquery UI dialog to implement the modal?

Comment: Why are you using **event.preventDefault()** ? It will prevent click action.